# Angular E2E test data: ngMockE2E or test data server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-e2e

I am developing an Angular app (Angular 1.1.5). I need some way of mocking REST API responses for e2e tests.

[AngularJS (Green & Seshadri)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/AngularJS-Brad-Green/dp/1449344852/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1383053200&sr=8-1&keywords=angularjs) goes into some detail on unit testing HTTP requests with `$httpBackend`, but has little to say about e2e tests.

The documentation suggests using [the `ngMockE2E` module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend) to mock `$httpBackend` (which is distinct from the normal unit testing `$httpBackend` mock.

I spent a few hours investigating the `ngMockE2E`API and, whilst I can see some benefits, there seem to be many downsides. My question is:

**What are the advantages of `ngMockE2E` over a simple server that provides test responses?** or, more generally, **What is the best way to test an Angular app's interactions with a server?**

I can think of a few disadvantages:

- I need to change my HTML to bootstrap the app with a different Angular module (a new one that depends on `ngMockE2E` and my actual application module)
- There are no HTTP requests for Firebug/Developer tools to inspect. This is a big one for me. I ended up writing request/response logging methods in my mock backend. I guess most mock back ends contain this kind of code.
- There isn't an easy way to extract parameters from URLs. If I wanted to the get the *id* parameter from `/resource/:id`, I'd need to give a regex to match the URL (`\/resource\/.+$`), then split the matching URL string on slash and pick the last element.
- The API is clunky. Returning a static object is simple, but dynamically determining which test object to return based on the requested URL is difficult. Some apps may be able to hard-code a complete set of test URLs, but I need to test a large number of resources so this is impractical for me. More complex code means there is more to go wrong.

I can also think of some advantages. When using `ngMockE2E`:

- I don't need to tell my app where the test API is - `$httpBackend` will inspect *all* HTTP requests for matches.
- I don't need to run a web server at all.
- I don't need to restart a server to pick up changes to my test data.
- There are fewer overall components in the tests. However, given that this is an integration test, this isn't a huge benefit.

Very interested in thoughts and experiences.

Comment: Are you using `karma` or `Protractor` to do your E2E tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion, several weeks of development later: I found a simple dummy backend (Node/Express) more flexible and maintanable than the e2e testing mock backend. The most compelling reasons are proper URL pattern matching and real HTTP requests for browser debugging.